# Passing a variable in a query string, where to create the variable

Tags: php, sql, database

I have created a program that will send an email to all of the emails in my database under the specific condition. My problem now, however, is that I needed to create a link in the message of the email that connects to another php page of mine. In that link I am required to pass the email address into the query string, but I never created the variable $email because I felt it was not necessary for my while loop. Any suggestions as to how I can go about resolving this?

http://localhost/unsubscribe.php?e=$email'>click here to unsubscribe

```
<?php

$subject = "New Sales";
$message = "25% off any item of your choice! <br>
        <a href=’http://localhost/unsubscribe.php?e=$email'>click here to unsubscribe</a>"; 

$headers = "From: email@yourdot.com";

 //create connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "student";
$dbname = "db1";

// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
} 



  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT emailAddress FROM members WHERE subscribe = 'YES' ");


    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if (isset($row->emailAddress)) {
        mail($row->emailAddress,$subject, $message, $headers);

}

}
echo "Email has been sent!"; 
?>
```

Any advice is helpful, but I do not want to get rid of the while loop, because this was the best option in my opinion. If there is a better alternative though, please inform me. Also keep it easy on me please. I am a noob.

Comment: You need to add $message in if condition in while loop so that it can be fetched dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you just simply want to pass the variable through the url you can pass it like this:

```
  <a href=’http://localhost/unsubscribe.php?e=<?php echo $email; ?>'>click here to unsubscribe</a>";
```

or

```
 <a href='unsubscribe.php?e=".$email."'>click here to unsubscribe</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your email message after if condition in while loop like below:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if (isset($row->emailAddress)) {
        $message = "25% off any item of your choice! <br>
        <a href=’http://localhost/unsubscribe.php?e=$row->emailAddress'>click here to unsubscribe</a>";
        mail($row->emailAddress,$subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!